# I just destroyed the booting software?

Tags: boot, chkdsk

Yesterday i decided to change my windows 8.1 for windows 7 for unexplainable reasons.. I just did it. So i ISOed an USB and bla bla till the point where you chose in what partition you install windows. In this section you can clean (format? Sorry im not english) delete and stuff partitions so i decided to delete every single partition letting only one 1TB big. I deleted EVERYTHING (complete NONSENSE, i know).

Now i got the bootmgr is missing screen plus no drivers plus no solution possible throug chkdsk commands. I cant even start the pc

Summary: i autoinduced my pc into the 0x80070570 error.

I know i deserve it for doing stupid stuff but i really am in a hurry cause i need to send emails to get a place in a Uni.

Could somebody reach me a helping hand i would be really really thankfull.
Thans in forward

Comment: Try software like Hetman NTFS Recovery for recovering your data on partitions. 0x80070570 error is on usb or hard drive, if it's on usb, transfer it to another computer and run error checking explained in this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HxD96oczGUI.

Answer (score 2):

Check your boot priority list in your BIOS. Did you already install windows on your "empty" partition?
Maybe you're trying to boot an empty harddisk -> in that case, make sure your flashdrive is the first device that your BIOS would boot.

Comment: I cant install windows because it stops at 43% with the error mentioned above. And yes the bios priority booting list is already configurated the way you told me. :S i broke my own pc?

Comment: What error do you get at 43% of the installation process? 0x80070570? If so you might have a broken file system. That might be fixable by reformatting the partition or by creating a smaller partition which is not covering the broken part of your HD. However, if you have a physically broken HD it would be wise to replace it before installing OS.

Comment: The hdd worked fine until i completely erased everything in it. Now i cant format or create another smaller partition because the windows window wont let me. How could i do that without usong the windows client?

Comment: You would have to use another client for this. Take your HDD out, and connect it through SATA to a working client (mac/linux/windows).
For windows: run 'diskmgmt.msc' in order to access it and format it a couple of times.
You can always use third-party software for this like Partition Magic.
Another useful tip, is the use of Hirens Boot CD [link](http://www.hiren.info/pages/bootcd) which contains a TON of tools for issues like this. With that boot CD you could use your current 'broken' client.

Comment: In case i dont get to repair it, simply by buying a new one the problem should be solved?

Comment: This would indeed solve your problem, but why buy a new HDD and throw the old one out, if it's not even broken?

Answer (score 0):

Your drive should not have suffered any permanent damage from having its partitions deleted. I suggest creating a 120GB system partition (for Win 7, others may require more or less) and use the leftover space for a game/storage partition. This allows for a future windows reinstall without loosing all your precious data.

The error 0x80070570 suggests that the filesystem on your installation media is corrupt. To resolve that simply find a working windows computer and run checkdisk on the USB partition to repair the filesystem.

If any of the files on the USB stick were corrupted you need to recreate the Windows 7 installation data on the usb stick. Alternatively you can burn the iso file to a dvd and install Windows 7 it using that instead.

Comment: Thank you! All of you guys! Im heading to a coffe place to use another pc to perform all the procedures you guys told me.